# Jquery UI button - css to make custom icon always appear before text, no matter how long is the text

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI with asp.net button to place custom icon on button.

In my css, i am using margin to move the cusom icon. If text is longer then i need to change the margin.

Is there any way to place icon alway before the text, no matter how long is the button text. (i don't have to create separate css for different buttons)

**Jquery for asp.net button**

```
$(function () {
    $("input:submit").button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'cssbox-okbtn'
        }
    }).hide().after('<button>').next().button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'cssbox-okbtn'
        },
        label: $("input:submit").val()
    }).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev().click();
    });
});
```

**cusom buttom css**

```
.cssbox-okbtn { 
background-image: url('/images/easyui/icons/ok.png') !important;
margin: 95px;      
}
```

asp.net page

```
<td align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin"" Text=" Login " runat="server"   />                            
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the traditional way, using `.ui-button-text { padding-left: ### }`? It would help if you make a snippet or fiddle or other demo

Comment: i have added screen shot